# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk.chunk.named_entity

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have been using pyinstaller and when I use my code and click a button it says.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk.chunk.named_entity
```

I do not know why?  In my code that I convert to a .exe file I include

```
#Imports
from nltk import ne_chunk, pos_tag, word_tokenize
from nltk.tree import Tree
from nltk.corpus import state_union
import bs4 as bs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
```

I have looked in the 'Dist' and could not find anything to do with nltk but it included other imports I have done except another module that I think was missing in the shape of 'bs4'. What can I do? Help would much be appreciated!

P.S My program works okay in the actual python code

Comment: have you tried  install nltk  modules separately and run?

Comment: How would I do that?